# How to allocate pitched 2D memory in CuPy?

Tags: python, c++, memory-management, cupy

In CuPy it is possible to allocate a multi-dimensional `ndarray` on the host, and then copy it to the GPU using CUDA. My questions are:

- does CuPy allocated memory have nice coalescing memory access properties for matrices (2D arrays) on the device, and if so, how is that related to `cupy.ndarray.strides`. If not, why not?
- why is CuPy is not using `cudaMalloc2D`, `cudaMalloc3D`, `cudaMallocPitch`?

My goal is to copy a 2D array with `width` and `height` to global memory (not texture memory - which *is* supported). In C++ I could do that with something like:

```
    float* devPtr = nullptr;
    size_t devPitch;
    cudaMallocPitch((void **) &devPtr, &devPitch, sizeof(float) * width, height);
    cudaMemcpy2D(devPtr, devPitch, my_array.data(),
                 width * sizeof(float), width * sizeof(float), height,
                 cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

But I cannot find a way in CuPy that seems to guarantee pitched properties, that I require in my custom kernel. I tried to "use the source, Luke" to find out what was really happening, but couldn't find an invocation to CUDA code that would achieve such result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pitched allocation is too specific for some domains and CuPy supports a range of use cases where matrices are being reshaped and views are created with different strides. Also, for some applications, the data is required to be contiguous and by using pitched allocations, Cuda automatically introduces padding between dimensions.

You can emulate this behavior yourself by allocating matrices with (height, pitch) and take the view with the shape (height, width). The values for the pitch should be adjusted to match the alignment with the desired data type.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to get the "optimal pitch" in CuPy such as is returned by `cudaMallocPitch`?

Comment: The pitch size seems to be always a multiple of 32.
https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~nguyenkt/posts/2019-07-31-cuda-malloc-pitch.html